# How to calculate available device storage?

Tags: android, storage, osmdroid

I'm using **OSMDroid** and trying to figure how much space I have on a device for offline tile storage.
The device is a **Samsung SM-T530NU**. It shows the following information:

```
Storage

Total space
Total device capacity
16.000GB

Owner
System memory
The minimum amount of storage space required to run the system.
4.05GB

Used space
The amount of storage space currently being used.
7.86GB

Cached data
0.93GB

Miscellaneous files
The amount of memory used to store miscellaneous files.
1.81GB

Other users
John Doe
121MB

Available space
The amount of storage space currently available
1.35GB
```

So if I calculate the total amount not used:

16GB - (7.86GB + 0.93GB + 1.81GB + .121GB) = 
16GB - 10.721 = 
5.279GB

Yet the available space is listed as 1.35GB.
Where is the other 3.929GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage device manufacturers measure capacity using the decimal system (base 10), so 1 gigabyte (GB) is calculated as exactly 1,000,000,000 bytes.

Storage capacity is measured by a prefix to the B (byte) to represent a specific amount, ie K (Kilobyte), M (Megabyte), G (Gigabyte), T (Terabyte) etc. Since all computers are based on the binary system, these prefixes represent base 2 amounts. Each level is an increment of 2 to the 10th power or 1,024.

The common prefixes are as follows:

- Kilobyte (KB) = 1,024 Bytes
- MegaByte (MB) = 1,024 Kilobytes or 1,048,576 Bytes
- Gigabyte (GB) = 1,024 Megabytes or 1,073,741,824 Bytes
- Terabyte (TB) = 1,024 Gigabytes or 1,099,511,627,776 Bytes

The capacity of storage in your device is measure using this decimal system.
Based on this, for each Gigabyte that a drive manufacturer claims, they are over reporting the amount of disk space by 73,741,824 Bytes 
or roughly 70.3 MB of disk space.

So, if a manufacturer advertises an 80 GB (80 billion bytes) hard drive, the actual disk space is around 74.5 GB of space, roughly 7% less than what they advertise.

```
Total space
Total device capacity
16.000GB -> 16,000,000,000/1024/1024 = approximately 15,259MB

Owner
System memory
The minimum amount of storage space required to run the system.
4.05GB -> 4,050,000,000/1024/1024 = approximately 3,862MB

Used space
The amount of storage space currently being used.
7.86GB -> 7,860,000,000/1024/1024 = approximately 7,496MB

Cached data
0.93GB -> 930,000,000/1024/1024 = approximately 887MB

Miscellaneous files
The amount of memory used to store miscellaneous files.
1.81GB -> 1,810,000,000/1024/1024 = approximately 1,726MB

Other users
John Doe
121MB -> 121,000,000/1024/1024 =  approximately 115,4MB

Available space
The amount of storage space currently available
1.35GB -> 1,350,000,000/1024/1024 =  approximately 1,287MB
```

So if I calculate the total amount not used:
15,259MB - (3,862MB + 7,496MB + 887MB + 1,726MB + 115,4MB) = approximately  1,173MB

Now the remaining value might not sound like a huge difference, but still has an approximation error.

My suggestion is to take a look at partitioning

```
$ adb shell cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

 253        0     486272 zram0
 179        0   15388672 mmcblk0
 179        1      65536 mmcblk0p1
 179        2        512 mmcblk0p2
 179        3       1024 mmcblk0p3
 179        4        512 mmcblk0p4
 179        5       2048 mmcblk0p5
 179        6        512 mmcblk0p6
 179        7       1024 mmcblk0p7
 179        8        512 mmcblk0p8
 179        9       2048 mmcblk0p9
 179       10       4096 mmcblk0p10
 179       11       4096 mmcblk0p11
 179       12        512 mmcblk0p12
 179       13        512 mmcblk0p13
 179       14       4096 mmcblk0p14
 179       15        512 mmcblk0p15
 179       16        512 mmcblk0p16
 179       17        512 mmcblk0p17
 179       18        512 mmcblk0p18
 179       19        512 mmcblk0p19
 179       20        512 mmcblk0p20
 179       21       1024 mmcblk0p21
 179       22        512 mmcblk0p22
 179       23       6656 mmcblk0p23
 179       24       6144 mmcblk0p24
 179       25        512 mmcblk0p25
 179       26        512 mmcblk0p26
 179       27       1536 mmcblk0p27
 179       28       1536 mmcblk0p28
 179       29       6144 mmcblk0p29
 179       30       6144 mmcblk0p30
 179       31      10240 mmcblk0p31
 259        0       8192 mmcblk0p32
 259        1      24576 mmcblk0p33
 259        2      24576 mmcblk0p34
 259        3      16384 mmcblk0p35
 259        4      16384 mmcblk0p36
 259        5      16384 mmcblk0p37
 259        6      57344 mmcblk0p38
 259        7      32768 mmcblk0p39
 259        8    3801088 mmcblk0p40
 259        9     512000 mmcblk0p41
 259       10     921600 mmcblk0p42
 259       11    9814016 mmcblk0p43
 259       12       4079 mmcblk0p44
 179       32       4096 mmcblk0rpmb
```

The eMMC(**mmcblk0**) size is **15388672**(1K-blocks) or approximately 15,028MB or 14.67GB

```
$ adb shell "ls -la /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/"
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  920 2015-12-31 22:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 1000 2015-12-31 22:31 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 DDR -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p13
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 OP -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p42
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 2015-12-31 22:31 aboot -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 2015-12-31 22:31 abootbak -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 boot -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p35
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 cache -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p41
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 config -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p22
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 devinfo -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p21
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 drm -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p29
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 eksst -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p19
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 encrypt -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p18
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 factory -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p38
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 fota -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p24
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 fsc -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p15
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 fsg -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p14
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 grow -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p44
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 keystore -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p17
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 laf -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p33
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 lafbak -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p34
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 misc -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p31
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 2015-12-31 22:31 modem -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 modemst1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 modemst2 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 mpt -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p39
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 persist -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p32
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 raw_resources -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p27
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 raw_resourcesbak -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p28
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 rct -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p25
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 recovery -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p36
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 recoverybak -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p37
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 2015-12-31 22:31 rpm -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 2015-12-31 22:31 rpmbak -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 2015-12-31 22:31 sbl1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 2015-12-31 22:31 sbl1bak -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 sec -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p16
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 sns -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p30
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 spare1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p23
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 spare2 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p26
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 spare3 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p20
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 ssd -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p12
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 system -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p40
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 2015-12-31 22:31 tz -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 2015-12-31 22:31 tzbak -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 2015-12-31 22:31 userdata -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p43
```

But remember that is 14.67Gb is the disk size and not the file system capacity

The command df stands for "disk filesystem". With the -h option (df -h) it shows the disk space in "human readable" form

```
$ adb shell df -h
Filesystem                             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                                  950M  1.1M  949M   1% /dev
tmpfs                                  950M     0  950M   0% /mnt
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system   3.5G  3.3G  141M  97% /system
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/cache    484M  576K  474M   1% /cache
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata 9.1G  570M  8.5G   7% /data
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/persist  3.8M  152K  3.5M   5% /persist
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/modem     64M   55M  9.4M  86% /firmware
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/sns      1.8M   44K  1.7M   3% /sns
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/drm      1.8M  356K  1.4M  20% /persist-lg
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/mpt       27M  4.2M   23M  17% /mpt
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/OP       872M  488M  368M  58% /OP
tmpfs                                  950M     0  950M   0% /storage
/dev/fuse                              9.1G  570M  8.5G   7% /storage/emulated
```

The device has 8.5G userdata available space as shown in the example above
Please note that userdata partition size is 9814016(mmcblk0p43) and the file system size is 9610592(9.1G)

references:

- http://www.ussscctv.com/hdccalc.html
- https://www.macworld.co.uk/feature/ipad/whats-iphone-ipod-ipads-true-formatted-storage-capacity-3511773/
- https://linux.die.net/man/1/df

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code may help you!!

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() *(long)stat.getBlockCount();
long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / 1048576;
System.out.println("Megs :"+megAvailable);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, When I run that code I get Megs = 12216, which is 12.216GB. Not sure what that means.